# html css glitch on android device

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, sass, visual-glitch

i'm working on a website using drupal 8, i'have done a carousel slider with image and bullet.
i've a strange glitch on device android device running android 5,6 and n on Google Chrome browser.
look at the image and at the html/css who generated this glitch.
Maybe can you tell me how is called this character, then i will me able to found a solution on internet.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

HTML :

```
 <div class="views-field-title">
        <div class="views-content-title">
            <div class="bullet">
                <div class="bullet-active">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SASS :

```
.views_slideshow_pager_field_item{
  width : 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display : block;
  float: left;
  margin : 10px;

  .views-field-title{
      //slider bullet
      .views-content-title{
        position: absolute;

        .bullet{
          color : blue;
          width : 16px;
          height: 16px;
          display : block;
          float: left;
          background : white;
          border-radius : 8px;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(black,0.6);
        }
      }
    }
    &.active{
      .views-field-title{
      //slider bullet
      .views-content-title{
        position: absolute;

        .bullet{
          //background : orange;
          .bullet-active{
            margin : 2px;
            width : 12px;
            height: 12px;
            border-radius : 6px;
            background : color(grey,3);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this SCSS, SASS or something like that? Because if it is pure CSS is not valid.

Comment: yes, this is  scss/sass code. i've updated my question.